# Why does Virtual Studio code keep failing to fine file or directory in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I run my code in Pythons build in IDLE Shell and it will run no problem. But once it is in virtual studio it then throws this error code.

I have gone into my Python Extension settings and have checked the 'Execute In File Dir' like multiple other posts and fixes say, but it does not seem to resolve my issue.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\Users\dpr48\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\FINAL PROJECT\Versions\v1.0.0\Cipher Text - 
v1.0.0\CipherText-v1.0.0.py", line 27, in <module>
    mainwindow = MainMenu()
 File "c:\Users\dpr48\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\FINAL PROJECT\Versions\v1.0.0\Cipher Text - 
v1.0.0\CipherText-v1.0.0.py", line 17, in __init__
    loadUi('MainMenu.ui', 'r', self)
 File "C:\Users\dpr48\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
   packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 238, in loadUi
    return DynamicUILoader(package).loadUi(uifile, baseinstance, resource_suffix)
 File "C:\Users\dpr48\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
   packages\PyQt5\uic\Loader\loader.py", line 66, in loadUi
 File "C:\Users\dpr48\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
   packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 1020, in parse
    document = parse(filename)
  File "C:\Users\dpr48\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", 
line 1229, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Users\dpr48\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", 
line 569, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'MainMenu.ui'
```

Comment: Have you checked whether it is related to the relative path?

Comment: looks like a case of `Where is Simon/MainMenu.ui`, print the current working directory to your stdout and compare. Don't you read the error message?

Comment: how do you want `to fine file`

Comment: @rioV8 Yes i read my error codes, im only a first year comp sci major some of the error code confuses me and im not 100% on how to go about them yet. Yes when i print the current working directory it is the same directory where the UI file is located.

Comment: First remove any spaces from your directory path, replace them with `_` if needed, why is the version number 3 times part of the file path

Comment: @rioV8 I removed the space and in 'FINAL PROJECT' and it seemed to resolve the issue.. And i have the version name in it multiple times just for organization compared to the other test versions. Can that also be throwing it off?

Comment: it only makes the path longer and adds no extra info, just like the `Versions` directory